# High CPU with mysql query when updating with inner join

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I have looked around allot and tried different methods and wanted to improve my import mechanic for big data. Importing data on insert works great, however I hit an issue when I want to update existing data based on 2 where statements.

I first load the data from source and place it in a CSV file, than use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE, to import the data in a temp table.

Than insert as followed from the temp table to the main table, which works as expected. Fast and uses a low amount of server resources.

```html
INSERT INTO $table ($fields) SELECT $fields FROM $temptable WHERE (ua,gm_id) NOT IN (SELECT ua,gm_id FROM $table)
```

I than have the following to update the records, the reason I created this method is because the update on duplicate key did not work. As it always inserted a new record. I think I don't understand how this method worked, or have not used it in the right way. Both UA and GM_ID are indexes on both tables, but can't get that to work. The issue with the below script is that, if I update 8000 rows, it uses 200% CPU and takes over 5 to 8 minutes. Which is of course not great.

```html
$query = "UPDATE $table a INNER JOIN $temptable b ON a.gm_id=b.gm_id AND a.ua=b.ua SET ";
    foreach($update_columns as $column => $status){
      $query .= "a.$column=b.$column,";
    }
    $query = trim($query, ",");
    $result = $pdo->query($query);
```

Can someone point me in the right direction what I should be using.

I want to update certain columns from the temp table to the main table. This code executes allot of times during the day. Sometimes can update just 100 rows, but sometimes 8k or 60k rows, and the columns can change.

I hope the sample codes are clear.

Thanks in advance for assistance.

Comment: When the key is same, why do you want to update non-key column with one of them, just keep the first inserted record and ignore the others, maybe also suitable.

Comment: @Forward Because the key's in both columns are not the same. And can only be updated based on both ua and gm_id requirement.

Comment: @zuluk I can't delete the original record as it contains values that need to be kept, which are not present in the temptable. Hence why only certain columns can be updated.

Comment: Sometimes it is more efficient to delete the index before update and recreate it after. That depends on your data.

Comment: Maybe you can take a more efficient datatype for id-columns: `SELECT gm_id FROM table1 PROCEDURE ANALYSE();`

Comment: Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Both UA and GM_ID are indexes on both tables" -- Two separate indexes is the wrong approach.  You must have a "composite" `UNIQUE(UA, GM_ID)` (in either order).  If that pair is not unique, then you cannot use IODKU.

`WHERE .. NOT IN ( SELECT ... )` is very inefficient.  `WHERE ... NOT EXISTS ( SELECT ... )` is better; `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE .. IS NULL` is even better.  See "SQL #1" in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization

Read the rest of that blog for more tips on high speed ingestion.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction. I will further test and read the referenced article. Thanks!

Comment: thank you very much, with your answer I have resolved my issue. Here is what I did. When creating the temp table, I keep the indexes, than insert missing rows and delete rows if they no longer exist. Than delete the two indexes on ua and gm_id on the temp table than perform the update script. This is now completed in less than 1 second and with no cpu issues.